# atom's command-line not work the same as the terminal in Mac

Tags: python, anaconda, atom-editor

I've been using atom editor and studying Python with Anaconda

I'm studying manipulating goole spread sheet

My question is my code works when executing via terminal in Mac, but not works in Atom and Atom's terminal

When checking conda list gspread is shown.

Here is my code

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
credentials = 
ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('cred.json', scope)
gs = gspread.authorize(credentials)
```

Mac terminal works

```
(fastcampusBasic) ➜  gspread_verify python3 verify.py         
(fastcampusBasic) ➜  gspread_verify
```

Atom terminal not works

```
(fastcampusBasic) ➜  gspread_verify python3 verify.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "verify.py", line 1, in <module>
import gspread
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gspread'
```

Atom execution not works(cmd+i)

I have certainly gspread in conda list

When using VScode It doesn't work in VScode excution(ctr+opt+n), but work in Vscode terminal

could anyone explain why I can't excute the code in Atom?

Comment: What plugin are you using for atom terminal ?

Comment: Are you using platformio-ide-terminal?  If not, load that extension and try again.

Comment: @jmh I'm using platformio-ide-terminal

Comment: @Feelsbadman I'm using platformio-ide-terminal I think I'd better user vscode